# requests.post returns {'code': 400, 'message': 'A CSV file must be provided in data field'}

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'am desperatly trying to turn the following CURL into a python code :

```
curl -X POST -F data=@C:\search.csv -F columns=NO_VOIE -F columns=TYPE_DE_VOIE -F columns=VOIE -F columns=CODE_POSTAL -F columns=COMMUNE -F result_columns=latitude -F result_columns=longitude -F result_columns=score https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/csv/
```

It goes without saying this CURL is working perfectly, giving a list a geocoded adresses, based on a CSV file `C:\search.csv` which stored the adresses to be geocoded with GPS tags.

```
search.csv =
INDEX,NO_VOIE,TYPE_DE_VOIE,VOIE,CODE_POSTAL,COMMUNE
201620160000000,77,RUE,TONY REVILLON,1750,SAINT-LAURENT-SUR-SAONE
201620160000001,,,LES BROTTEAUX,1160,VARAMBON
201620160000002,,,LES BROTTEAUX,1160,VARAMBON
201620160000003,,,LES BROTTEAUX,1160,VARAMBON
201620160000004,5246,,LES BROTTEAUX,1160,VARAMBON
```

My python 3.7 code is :

```py
import requests

url = 'https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/csv/'

params = {'data':'c:\search.csv',
         'columns':'VOIE'}

output = requests.post (url,json=params).json()

print (output)

{'code': 400, 'message': 'A CSV file must be provided in data field'}
```

S.O.S

API doc is here : https://geo.api.gouv.fr/adresse

Comment: `params = {'data':'c:\search.csv', 'columns':'VOIE'}` This is just the _filename_.  You need to provide the file _content_.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your quick answer. I'am not sure to get you. Should I have to do an os.open + os.read on the search.csv file and the transmit the opened+read file to the api ? There is no 'filename' parameter in the API documentation.

Comment: Sending just the filename won’t do anything useful; you need to send the file content.